# Simple future example

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do a simple future example. I followed https://blog.logrocket.com/a-practical-guide-to-async-in-rust/

So I did:

```
use futures::Future;
type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;

pub async fn receive_fut(
        f: &mut dyn FnMut(&[u8])
) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Vec<u8>>> {
    futures::future::ok(Ok(Vec::new())).await
}
```

but I get

```
error[E0277]: `std::result::Result<std::result::Result<Vec<_>, _>, _>` is not a future
 --> src/lib.rs:6:10
  |
6 |     ) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Vec<u8>>> {
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::result::Result<std::result::Result<Vec<_>, _>, _>` is not a future
  |
  = help: the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<std::result::Result<Vec<_>, _>, _>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Why std::result::Result should implement future, if I used `futures::future::ok` to turn it into a future result?

Comment: Im pretty sure thats rust and not c++, wrong tag?

Comment: @DownloadPizza fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in the article:

> Async functions differ in one important way: all your return types are “wrapped” into a `Future`.
>
> You might read the documentation about `Futures` in Rust and think your async function needs to look like this:
>
> ```
> async fn our_async_program() -> impl Future<Output = Result<String>> {
>     future::ok("Hello world".to_string()).await
> }
> ```
>
> This is wrong! If you’re doing this, you’re overthinking it. An `async` function already wraps the return type, so you can write functions the way you’re used to.
>
> This is what you actually want:
>
> ```
> async fn our_async_program() -> Result<String> {
>     future::ok("Hello world".to_string()).await
> }
> ```

So you'd want to drop the `impl Future<...` part of the return type:

```
pub async fn receive_fut(
        f: &mut dyn FnMut(&[u8])
) -> Result<Vec<u8>> {
    futures::future::ok(Ok(Vec::new())).await
}
```

And then realize that [`future::ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/future/fn.ok.html) already yields a `Result::Ok`, so you don't need to wrap it in `Ok()` again.

```
pub async fn receive_fut(
        f: &mut dyn FnMut(&[u8])
) -> Result<Vec<u8>> {
    futures::future::ok(Vec::new()).await
}
```

Comment: What about returning errors? `futures::future::err(std::io::Error::from_raw_os_error(1)).await` wont work

Comment: Well that's a different question, but `from_raw_os_error()` makes a `std::io::Error` which is not a `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`. However it can be [converted into one](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a99303b24427fb9b495b8554224dab94) using `.into()`.